# Find $P(X_{(1)} < \mu < X_{(4)})$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, X3, X4$ be iid random variables from a normal distribution with a mean of $\mu$.

Find $P(X_{(1)} < \mu < X_{(4)})$

My try:

$P(X_{(1)} < \mu < X_{(4)})$ = $P(\mu < X_{(4)})$ - $P(\mu < X_{(1)})$

And I know how to get the distributions of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(4)}$. But I think there must be a simpler way to find $P(X_{(1)} < \mu < X_{(4)})$. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X_{(1)} < \mu < X_{(4)})&=1-P(X_{(4)}<\mu)-P(\mu<X_{(1)})\\
&=1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^4\\
&=\boxed{\dfrac78}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: how did you get those probabilities? I mean, whats the logic behind  $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4$?

Comment: @SofíaContreras, the distribution is symmetric about the mean $\mu$. So $P[X<\mu]=P[X>\mu]=\dfrac12$ for $X$ following normal distribution with mean $\mu$.